# How do I make modification in java class hosted on a tomcat server faster?

Tags: java, spring, apache, tomcat, server

I have a java codebase in form a war hosted on Apache tomcat server(Production server). Now let us say i make changes in my class and i want the same to reflect on my hosted codebase. Do i have to re-start the server every time after updating the class, or is there some better way to do it

Comment: Look into redeploying war-files.

Answer (score 0):

You can use auto-deploy feature of tomcat. Read the [documentation](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/deployer-howto.html#Deploying_on_a_running_Tomcat_server) here.

---

If it is a development testing server, you can enable debugging, and reload your changed classes without having to restart the server or redeploying your webapp.

You can enable debugging by setting the following and restarting tomcat. (you can use a desired port):

```
-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=8787
```

In your IDE, create a debug configuration specifying server ip and the debug port you specified.

After connecting debugger, your IDE will usually prompt you to reload changed classes whenever you compile a class.

[image]

There is also a menu item also if you want to manually reload changed classes. Once you reload classes, your changes will be immediately effective.